# How to convert JSON Parse object property into array?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In mysql database, "diagID" is saved as json_encoded(array). Now i need it to retrieve in ajax success.

How to convert JSON parse data into array, as it's showing string?

```
var ajaxResponse= {
   "id": "123",
   "diagID" : "['101','125','150','230']"
}

typeof(ajaxResponse.diagID)
= string
```

In javascript typeof(ajaxResponse.diagID) shows string. How to convert it into array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoding it in php would make most sense

```
$diagID = json_decode($diagID, true);
```

Then when you `json_encode()` the whole response it won't have the extra wrapping quotes.

Note however that the strings in array have single quotes which are not valid json and need to be replaced with double quotes before they can be parsed in either language

Comment: I did it already with `var ajaxResponse= JSON.parse(response)`;

Problem is ajaxResponse.diagID is adding extra quotes, not ajaxResponse. (In Javascript);